# How to create exception classes in java

Tags: java, exception

I'm new to forums and Java in general. I'm trying to understand exceptions a little better. I have created a class which sorts an array of ints and prints the smallest value. Also I created an exception class which I want to throw if the array contains zero elements. I'm having trouble though as eclipse is telling me I have an "Unreachable catch block, this exception is never thrown from the try statement body". I have no idea what this means or how to fix it. Here is my code. I have a feeling its something small but obviously important. If anyone could help me with something I've missed I would be grateful.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exercise1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException { 
        //int[] array = { };
        int result = 0;
        int[] array = { 16, 14, 15, 12, 102, 88, 64, 1 , -3 }; 

        try {
            result = Exercise1.min(array);
            System.out.print(result);
        }
        catch (ArrayOutOfBoundsException noElements) {
            System.out.print("There are no elements in this array: " + noElements.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static int min(int[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);
        int minValue = array[0];
        return minValue;
    }
}


public class ArrayOutOfBoundsException extends Exception {

    public ArrayOutOfBoundsException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix indentation

Comment: @MiserableVariable: I think that one reason why his indentations are all over, is because he may be mixing tab indentations with space indentations. To the original poster, stick with one or the other. Myself I prefer using spaces, and not many, 2-3 for each block of code is usually sufficient for this site, but do strive to make your code indentations regular and conform to standards so that your code is readable.

Comment: `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` is not an exception thrown by either line in your try. Your Try should be around `int minValue = array[0]`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes agreed. Sorry I didn't realise

Comment: @Ghost When I try to surround int minValue = array[0] with a try statement, eclipse then says my return variable is uninitialised

Comment: @JohnSetter: you've got it all backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with Checked Exceptions in Java for you to catch it some method within your try block has to declare that it will throw it.  If you modify the declaration of min to explicitly state that it can throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, now your try/catch logic is clear to catch it and the compiler will stop complaining.

```
public static int min( int[] array ) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if ( array == null || array.length == 0 ) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Arrays.sort( array );
    int minValue = array[0];
    return minValue;
}
```

As a use-case, though, declaring your own ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException makes little sense.  Java already has an Exception for this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html, albeit a Runtime (unchecked) exception.

Comment: This is a great help. However the compiler is still complaining because my exception class constructor takes a String parameter, and when I call the constructor I have no String to put in it. I read in a book that it should but I'm not sure why. What String is it exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Your method, `min(...)`, should ***throw*** a new Exception of interest when applicable, and it should be declared that it throws this exception in the method signature.

i.e.,

```
public int myMethod(MyParam someParameter) throws MyExceptionClass {

    boolean somethingIsNotRight = .....; 

    if (somethingIsNotRight) {
      throw new MyExceptionClass("My text passed into exception");
    } else {
      // continue processing my code
    }
}
```

Then the code that calls that method, here your main method, should catch it and handle it. Note that the main method should not be declared to throw this same exception, because it will be handling it.